# Magento 2 custom module routes are not picked up

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I have a clean install of Magento 2 and am trying to create a really simple custom module, but it doesn't seem to recognize any of the code in the module. The module itself shows up in the list in the back-end, and can be enabled, but (for example) custom routes in routes.xml always go to a 404 page.

This is not just happening for new custom modules that I create, but also for modules downloaded from elsewhere. I get a 404 when I install Alan Storm's "Hello World" module (http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_mvvm_mvc) and try to navigate to /hello_mvc/hello/world. I also get a 404 on navigating to /newpage after installing the sample module Sample New Page.

I have cleared the cache, set the mode to developer, run `setup:upgrade` and `setup:di:compile`. Other pages, such as the /customer/account/ page, work fine, so it's not the rewriting that's the issue (I don't think).

I'm on Windows 8.1 running WAMP with (the standard) Apache 2.4.18, PHP 7.0.4 & MySQL 5.7.11. I've tried the latest 2 versions of Magento 2 (2.0.4 & 2.0.5) and have the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I didn't get to the bottom of why this was happening, but after a clean install of Magento I have now been able to get this working.